# wp job manager how to change behaviour based on job types

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to implement changes for the user based on job type (work-wanted) so that when accessing from the jobs board it won't have 'apply for job' and won't show resume details but allow for employers to contact the candidate. I found this excerpt from wp-job-manager-template.php that perhaps might offer a clue? im new to all this sorry, any help would be much appreciated. I've just had my first actual listing and it looks silly having these options on the live site! I'm thinking the $job_types or $employment_types could be used in a filter then present information based on that. On the job board, i'm not sure where the 'appy for job' button comes from or how to implement these changes.
thanks

```
    /**
 * Get the employment types for the job listing.
 *
 * @since 1.28.0
 *
 * @param WP_Post|int|null $post
 * @return bool|array
 */
function wpjm_get_job_employment_types( $post = null ) {
    if ( ! wpjm_job_listing_employment_type_enabled() ) {
        return false;
    }
    $employment_types = [];
    $job_types        = wpjm_get_the_job_types( $post );

    if ( ! empty( $job_types ) ) {
        foreach ( $job_types as $job_type ) {
            $employment_type = get_term_meta( $job_type->term_id, 'employment_type', true );
            if ( ! empty( $employment_type ) ) {
                $employment_types[] = $employment_type;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter the employment types for a job listing.
     *
     * @since 1.28.0
     *
     * @param array            $employment_types Employment types.
     * @param WP_Post|int|null $post
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wpjm_get_job_employment_types', array_unique( $employment_types ), $post );
}
```

Comment: Ive found this (job-application.php) and added to my child theme to override the template how to add a reference to the post tag id? ie. if  ( $apply = get_the_job_application_method() ) && somethinghere :

Comment: if ( $apply = get_the_job_application_method() )  :
 wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-job-manager-job-application' );
 ?>
 <div class="job_application application">
  <?php do_action( 'job_application_start', $apply ); ?>

  <input type="button" class="application_button button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply for Job', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>" />

  <div class="application_details">
   <?php
    
    do_action( 'job_manager_application_details_' . $apply->type, $apply ); 
   ?>
  </div>
  <?php do_action( 'job_application_end', $apply ); ?>
 </div>
 



<?php endif; ?>